# Find the radius of the arc?

Tags: geometry

A door with a width $4.20$ m has an arc as shown in the diagram. Find:

a) the radius of the arc, to the nearest cm

b) the length of the arc, to the nearest cm.

---

I need help in part a). For b), we can use the formula $L=r \theta$.
You can see the picture in the link.

[The radius of the arc length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvy9f.png)

[My idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqy4.png)

Comment: You know the chord length and the angle it subtends at the center. Can you use trig to get the radius?

Comment: You need trigonometry. Find the right triangle...

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan, I understand and tried it but it seems wrong. I am confused about the angle. The outer angle is 225. What about the inner angle? Do we need to find the inner angle first to apply the trigonometric formulas?

Comment: Can you post your attempts? As a hint I can tell you to use the triangle with the internal angle and the chord, and drop the perpendicular bisector from the centre to the chord

Comment: @zaidizee Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan. This is my idea. But I am confused about the value of $\theta$. Can you please help me in it? I already updated my idea in the question in a picture form.

Comment: @zaidizee The outer angle is $225°$, so the inner angle is $360-225 = 135°$.

Comment: Understand. Do we need to further divide the inner angle? In formula, it is $\theta /2$.

Comment: Yes, you need to halve the inner angle. Then apply the trigonometric ratios.

Comment: @Toby Mak It means: $r = x/sin(67.5) = 420/ 0.74 = 567.57cm$. Is it correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You need to halve the $4.20$ metres as well. For part $b$, you need to convert the inner angle to *radians* to be able to use the formula $l = r \theta$.

Comment: @Toby Mak Now is it correct? $r = x/sin(67.5) = 210/ 0.74 = 283.78cm$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS

The radius

$$ R= \dfrac{ 2.1}{\sin 67.5^{\circ}}$$
$$ Arc= R\; 3 \pi/4. $$

[image]